# issue in for loop when using dynamic loop of array in javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at saveSign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the below error in this code in for loop but when i give iput+=checkedBoxes[1].id staticaly means it is working please help and also alert in for loop is working with s

> ERROR : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at saveSign

```
function saveSign(){
   alert('asd')
   var iput =[];
   var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
   for (var s=1;s<=checkedBoxes.length;s++){
     iput+=checkedBoxes[s].id
   }
   console.log(iput)
}
```

Comment: alert(s) inside for loop is working and iput+=checkedBoxes[1].id is also working

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').checked like this anyway to get  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').unchecked like that need to get un checked checkbox values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with your for loop's loop counter.  It starts at 1, skipping the first array element, then proceeds up to the length, at which index in the array exists no element.  You can avoid loop counters altogether with a for-of loop or a `forEach` callback.

I also noticed you were using the `+=` operator on an array (`iput`).  To append elements to an array, you use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.  If you wanted a string, set `iput` to an empty string (`''`) and keep the `+=`.

Lastly, you omitted a few semicolons.  With the pitfalls of automatic semicolon insertion, it's easier to just use them whenever possible to avoid unexpected behavior.

Using a normal for loop:

```
function saveSign() {
   const iput = [];
   const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
   for(let i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
     iput.push(checkedBoxes[i].id);
   }
   console.log(iput);
}
```

Using a [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
function saveSign() {
   const iput = [];
   const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
   for(const checkedBox of checkedBoxes) {
     iput.push(checkedBox.id);
   }
   console.log(iput);
}
```

Using a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) callback:

```
function saveSign() {
   const iput = [];
   const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
   checkedBoxes.forEach((checkedBox) => {
     iput.push(checkedBox);
   });
   console.log(iput);
}
```

Comment: thanks @kamoroso94 now i am using  for-of loop as per your guidance and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is being thrown when `s` reaches the last element in the array. You should iterate from 0 to `checkedBoxes.length`

```
for (var s = 0;s < checkedBoxes.length; s++){
    iput += checkedBoxes[s].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1.
In your case, the last iteration of your loop is out of range of your array.

To work around all your array you need to define your loop like this :

```
for ( var s = 0; s < checkedBoxes.length; s++ ){

}
```